# NGRX Multiple stores or nested State?

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store

I am trying to implement the NGRX State to manage user-defined preferences throughout my application. I want each Module to be able to contribute settings to the preferences State, and ideally I would like the preference state to be hierarchical so that modules can have their own namespace, e.g:

```
{
    user: 'someuser',
    preferences: {
        module1prefs: {
            pref1: 'abc',
            pref2: 'xyz'
        },
        module2prefs: {
            pref3: 123,
            pref4: 456
        }
    }
}
```

I was originally hoping to be able to create a nested hierarchy off of a shared feature in the Root NGRX state (i.e. preferences in the example above). This would have enabled me to add an Observer to the selector for this root feature to trigger periodic (REST API) save operations. It would also make it easy for me to build a single JSON preference document to send to the server to be saved.

From [what I have been reading](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/395), sharing a single NGRX feature across modules is not recommended.

Please could you therefore recommend an approach or best practice that satisfies my requirements:

1. Multiple modules can contribute their preference settings to the State
2. The State is easy to Observe from a single Observer (to trigger persistence to the server)
3. The State is easy to serialize to a single JSON document that can be sent to the server to persist all preferences

Comment: You could have a selector for each module preference and a selector which combine everything you need

Comment: You could try Akita instead.

Comment: you can have them to be `feature` store

Comment: This is exactly what the `StoreModule.forFeature('your-feature')` functionality will accomplish. Each module you add can add its own slice of state and you can create selectors that slice and dice the data to suit your needs.

Comment: @Brandon - It was my understanding that the forFeature() would add the 'preferences' node to the root, but how would I add a sub-node for each Module (i.e. module1prefs and module2prefs in the example above)? NOTE: My goal is to have a single root node in the state tree so that I can observe it for changes to any preferences without the need to observe each and every preference for modifications.

Comment: Each feature state is it's own key on the root. You can watch the entire state tree for changes just as easy as watching a particular slice.

Comment: Thanks @Brandon, the listening side is easy, but where I'm having trouble is, how to have multiple modules register their reducers on a shared feature in order for each module to contribute their preferences to the shared feature (i.e. to achieve item #1 in my list above). Is this possible?

Comment: @Nick That's a good question. I've never specifically tried to add a feature module to another feature, but it still sounds like you could at least get the slices of state you want through selectors. One for the "shared" feature as a whole, and then a feature selector for each of your other modules using the shared selector as the starting point.